# Cordova Splash Screen location issue

Tags: cordova

The config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="a.b.c9" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"      

 xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

    <name>Sample Application</name>

    <description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="www/img/splashscreen.png" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

</widget>
```

The location of config.xml and splashscreen.png goes like this

```
projectdirectory/www/img/splashscreen.png
projectdirectory/config.xml
```

Thanks for your help in advance, SO Flow!

**content added**

I am currently reading the cordova splashscreen plugin page on GitHub

and it says I must have this in my config.xml

I wonder what should replace "foo" if I am adding multiple png files with different sizes inside that project

Comment: which platform or platforms are added to this project?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Android and when Android is complete, I will also build one for iOS.  By the way, my Cordova is 3.6.3 and I also added splashscreen plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to place `splashscreen.png` into the correct folder for each platform.

Android: `platforms/android/res/drawable` (and any other drawable folders for other resolutions -hdpi, etc)

iOS: `platforms/ios/{PROJECT_NAME}/Resources/splash`

Then set your config setting to:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splashscreen" />
```

After you do those steps run `cordova build`